# Lost the gradle build scan link

Tags: gradle, privacy

When we do ./gradlew build --scan we receive a build scan link which first needs to be activated and then the same link can be used to access the build scan.

I was trying to generate a build scan with gradle but I have lost the build scan link which is generated at the end before even activating the link with my email, thus I don't have it in my email.

Now I wanted to delete the build scan  but I don't have the generated link. Is there any way which allows me to get the generated link so that I can delete the build scan?

I know that I can generate a new build scan, but the issue here is that I want to delete that particular build scan which I generated earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Gradle scans.gradle.com, the unactivated or reviewd build scans are deleted after 3 months.

> A Build Scan that has not been viewed within 3 months of being created will be removed. Once a Build Scan has been viewed, it will be available indefinitely.